# Convertors converting unconverted objects

Tags: c#, converting, wpf

In my app, I have several convertors, like these two:

```
public class ThemeToTableStripeConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        if ((int)value == 1) { return new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 34, 34, 34)); }
        return new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 238, 238, 238));
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        return null;
    }
}

public class ThemeToLBStyleConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        if ((int)value == 1) { return Application.Current.Resources["LBDark"]; }
        else if ((int)value == 2) { return Application.Current.Resources["LBGold"]; }
        else { return Application.Current.Resources["LBLight"]; }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

In the first, I have an `int` representing a theme style, with 0, 1, and 2 being the three themes I support.  Themes 0 and 2 are identical in the part affected by this (white background), while 1 has a black background.  In the second, I want theme 0 to always be the default, no matter the value, and themes 1 and 2 to return different items.

Beyond the general comments, there are a couple things I would like specific feedback on.  Both of these convertors are one-way convertors, and always will be; however, that `return null;` looks a little off - should I replace that with `throw new NotImplementedException();`?  Instead of formatting my code like this:

```
if (condition) { return val1; }
return val2;
```

Should I write that as:

```
if (condition) { return val1; }
else { return val2; }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Avoid long one-liners:**

This:

```
if ((int)value == 1) { return new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 34, 34, 34)); }
```

Should be:

```
if ((int)value == 1)
{
    return new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 34, 34, 34));
}
```

Typically one-liner if-statements are-so because they're short and can't be justified to take up 3 lines for something so small.

**Avoid 'else' one-liners:**

This is a clutter:

```
if (condition) { return val1; }
else { return val2; }
```

This isn't as big of a clutter, just space-consuming:

```
if (condition) 
{ 
    return val1; 
}
else 
{ 
    return val2; 
}
```

**Acceptable alternatives:**

I would do the following for maximum readability:

```
return condition ? val1 : val2;
```

Making use of the ternary operator and being the most maintainable/readable method.

In cases where you're not able to keep it one line, something like you had above is perfectly acceptable:

```
if (condition) { return val1; }
// Do something...?
return val2;
```

**One-way converters:**

I would consider the following situation before throwing an `NotImplementedException()`.

```
public interface IOneWayValueConverter
{
    object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language);
}

// Optionally Adding "TwoWay" to the name (or some other similar naming method).
public interface IValueConverter : IOneWayValueConverter
{
    object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language);
}
```

If this isn't an option (for any number of reasons) then it would seem the only acceptable answer to this situation would be throwing a `NotImplementedException()` as you stated.

Comment: I would also add that you are using magic numbers this isn't recommended, you should consider using an enum instead.

Comment: That came to mind to me too, I just tried to stick to his concerns since It was only my second answer on the site :P